# Android Fragment with attached AsyncTask gives null after commit in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I try to understand basic design pattern behind implementing AsyncTask and attaching it to Fragment. I follow numerous tutorials and implemented code (which gives nothing):
1) my Fragment class which contains AsyncTask:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    public interface TaskCallback
    {
        void onPreExecute();
        void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i);
        void onPostExecute();
    }
    private TaskCallback mCallback;
    private Task mTask;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (TaskCallback) activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mTask = new Task();
        mTask.execute();
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            mCallback.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                publishProgress(i*10);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            mCallback.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            mCallback.onPostExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

2) my Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MyFragment.TaskCallback
{
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private MyFragment mTaskFragment;
    private final static String TAG_FRAGMENT = "Fragment Task";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        mProgress.setProgress(0);

        //create fragment manager and fragment instance
        FragmentManager mFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mTaskFragment = (MyFragment) mFM.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);

        if(mFM == null)
        {
           mTaskFragment = new MyFragment();
           mFM.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }
//I added this method, but to no help, the same without this method
       mFM.executePendingTransactions();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i)
    {
        mProgress.setProgress(i[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute()
    {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Basically, when run the code by Debug, after

```
mTaskFragment = (MyFragment) mFM.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
    if(mFM == null)
    {
       mTaskFragment = new MyFragment();
       mFM.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
```

Gives `mTaskFragment = null`

I suppose here is the problem (mTaskFragment = null), the code doesn't create instance of MyFragment.

The question: how should I change the code to update ProgressBar from background by using this (Fragment + AsyncTask) pattern?

 another question: Fragment onAttached(Activity a) is deprecated, now we should use onAttached(Context context), does it mean it should be implemented like: `mCallback = (TaskCallback) context;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  `if(mFM == null)` with `if(mTaskFragment == null)` you want to check if the fragment is null not the FragmentManager.

Also the updated method for:

`public void onAttach(Activity activity)` is `public void onAttach(Context context)`

Using: `mCallback = (TaskCallback) context;` is fine as `Context` is a superclass of `Activty` (just make sure your Activity is implementing the interface)

Comment: Thank you! `if(mTaskFragment == null)` solves the problem. It's embarrassing how simple it was and how much I struggled to find it.

Comment: No problem, updated answer to include your other question